# How to isolate x in this case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the following equations:

> $x^3 + px + q = 0$
>
> $x = u + v $
>
> $p=-3uv$

Where $q$ and $p$ are known real numbers and $x$ is an unknown real number. We want to find an equation for $x$ by first writing one for $u$ and $v$. So we get:

$$ (u+v^3) - (u+v)3uv +q = 0$$

$$ u^3 + v^3 = -q$$

$$ (u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2) = -q$$

$$ x((u+v)^2 - 3uv) = -q $$

$$ x(x^2+p) = -q $$

But after this I hit a brick wall. I can't seem to isolate the $x$ for the life of me, where did I go wrong?

Comment: You'll notice that you've arrived back at your original equation! :)  Try combining $u^3 + v^3 = - q$ with the fact that $p^3 = - 27 u^3 v^3$. (To reduce exponent clutter, you can think of this as $U+V=-q$ and $p^3 = -27 UV$. Solve for $U$ and $V$.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You have two equations:

$u^3 + v^3 = -q,\,\,p=-3uv$